# How to load ng2-smart-table with the new data after adding data?

Tags: angular, typescript, ng2-smart-table

Whenever I add new data to the table, the table should load automatically. The data gets loaded to the database. But the table doesnot gets updated. Is there a way to achieve this?

### myHtmlPage.html

```
<ng2-smart-table [settings]="progressTable_Config" 
                 [source]="progressTableSource"
                 (createConfirm)="addProgressRecord($event)" 
                 (deleteConfirm)="onDeleteConfirm($event)">
```

### myComponentFile.ts

```
progressTable_Config = {
    add: {
      addButtonContent: '<i class="nb-plus"></i>',
      createButtonContent: '<i class="nb-checkmark"></i>',
      cancelButtonContent: '<i class="nb-close"></i>',
      confirmCreate: true,
    },
    edit: {
      editButtonContent: '<i class="nb-edit"></i>',
      saveButtonContent: '<i class="nb-checkmark"></i>',
      cancelButtonContent: '<i class="nb-close"></i>',
      confirmEdit: false,
    },
    delete: {
      deleteButtonContent: '<i class="nb-trash"></i>',
      confirmDelete: true,
    },
    actions: {
      add: true,
      edit: false,
      delete: false,
    },
    columns: {
      progress_date: {
        title: 'Date',
        type: 'date',
        filter: false
      },
      progress_percent: {
        title: 'Percentage Completed(%)',
        type: 'integer',
        filter: false,
      },
      note: {
        title: 'Note',
        type: 'string',
        filter: false
      },
    },
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to refresh maybe this code help you

```
this.progressTableSource.refresh();
```

or

```
this.progressTableSource.empty();
this.progressTableSource.refresh();
this.progressTableSource.load(this.data);
```